# Print total value in footer but unable to modify footer value using hook_views_pre_render()

Tags: views, 9

Using below code to modify footer value in hook_views_pre_render() but it's not working

```
function hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  foreach($view->result as $result) {
    $totalamt = $result->_entity->amount->value + $totalamt;
  }
  $options = array(
      'id' => 'area_1',
      'table' => 'views',
      'field' => 'area_text_custom',
      'relationship' => 'none',
      'group_type' => 'none',
      'admin_label' => '',
      'empty' => TRUE,
      'tokenize' => FALSE,
      'content' => 'Total is:'. $totalamt,
      'plugin_id' => 'text_custom',
    );
    $view->setHandler('page_1', 'footer', 'area_1', $options);
}
```

Comment: With apologies if this is a silly question: Is `hook_views_pre_render` the actual name of the function or did you replace “hook” with the module name?

Comment: Apart from that, three suggestions. (1) When creating new hooks or altering the names of existing hooks, always clear your caches. (2) Drupal coding standards, which means short array syntax and two space indentations. If your site is meant to live for a while, a uniformly formatted code base makes it easier to maintain. (3) Check out this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator - Sometimes you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It works when we use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator
thanks  @Mario Steinitz

Answer (score 1):

If that is a copy of your code, you need to replace the `hook` word in the function name `hook_views_pre_render` with your module name.

EG. Your module is called `mymodule`

`hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view)` => `mymodule_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view)`

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/hooks

Comment: Replaced hook with module name eg:
web_module_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view)
Still footer value is not changing.